# How to add hyphens between elements of a string?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have 6 different strings that I have combined together in a certain order to achieve what I want.

```
for a, b, c, d, e, f in zip(titles, artists, countrys, companys, values, years):
    print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

I used a zip function to print each element of each string one by one.

I just need to add a hyphen between each element.

So for example one line of my output looks like this:

```
Empire Burlesque Bob Dylan USA Columbia 10.9 1985
```

But I need this:

```
Empire Burlesque - Bob Dylan - USA - Columbia - 10.9 - 1985
```

The hyphens separate each element of the 6 strings.

I was thinking whitespace replace but that would replace too much.

Any help is appreciated ! Thank you !

Comment: `for i in zip(titles, artists, countrys, companys, values, years):  print(' - '.join(i))`  might need a `list(i)`

Answer (score 2):

The print-function can do that when you supply the keyword argument `sep`:

```
for a, b, c, d, e, f in zip(titles, artists, countrys, companys, values, years):
    print(a, b, c, d, e, f, sep=" - ")
```

Or as an easier way for dealing with large collections: **Note that your arguments should be strings then.**

```
for description in zip(titles, artists, countrys, companys, values, years):
    print(" - ".join(description))
```

If it's not all string, `print` can handle different types and you could unpack your description:

```
for description in zip(titles, artists, countrys, companys, values, years):
    print(*description, sep=" - ")
```

Approach that allows for formatting:

```
for description in zip(titles, artists, countrys, companys, values, years):
    print("{} by {} from {} produced by {} going for {}$ (Year {})".format(*description))
```

Comment: Talon you're the best. Thanks for your help!